How to add custom extractor to yt-dlp?
I want to make a custom extractor for https://www.buzzsprout.com in order to extract season and episode numbers in addition to what generic extractor already does.
This is my script saved at:
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yt_dlp/extractor/buzz.py
from yt_dlp.extractor.common import InfoExtractor
import re

class BuzzSproutIE(InfoExtractor):
    IE_NAME = 'buzzsprout'
    _VALID_URL = r'https://www.buzzsprout.com/.*/(?P<id>[^/?#&]+)$'

    def _real_extract(self, url):
        video_id = self._match_id(url)
        webpage = self._download_webpage(url, video_id)

        # Extract the season number.
        season = self._search_regex(
            r'<span class="whitespace-nowrap">Season (\d+)</span>',
            webpage,
            'season',
            fatal=False
        )
        # Extract the episode number.
        episode = self._search_regex(
            r'<span class="whitespace-nowrap">Episode (\d+)</span>',
            webpage,
            'episode',
            fatal=False
        )

        return {
            'id':      video_id,
            'title':   self._html_search_regex(r'<title>([^<]+)</title>', webpage, 'title'),
            'season':  season,
            'episode': episode,
        }


And I have added this line to /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yt_dlp/extractor/_extractors.py:
from .buzz import BuzzSproutIE

But yt-dlp --list-extractors | grep -i buzz still doesn't show my extractor and https://www.buzzsprout.com urls are still handled by generic extractor.
What am I missing?
